# Anyone know how to create an Expander in the SketchFlow style?

Tags: wpf, expander, sketchflow

I've checked the Expression Blend + Sketchflow forum, and also looked through the Gallery, but haven't found an expander control that's in the SketchFlow style.  Can anyone point me to one, or offer me advice on how I can roll my own Sketchflow Expander control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that there is not one included with SketchFlow.  Are you looking for Silverlight or WPF?

Comment: WPF -- that's the only way you can use SketchFlow, isn't it?

Comment: SketchFlow works for Silverlight projects as well.  When you create a new project, you can also create a new SketchFlow Silverlight project.